# Help Answering a Conditional Probability Question

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn conditional probability and I came up with a question to practice with. I was hoping someone could walk me through it so I can check my work.

```
-The probability of watching 15+ tv episodes given that it's Sunday is 63%.
-The probability of watching less than 15 episodes given that it's not Sunday is 43%.
-The probability that it's Sunday is 14%.
```

What's the probability that it's not Sunday, given that you watched 15+ tv episodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Well, there are two ways in which that could have happened.

(Note:  I will use $\frac 17$ as the probability that it is Sunday.

I.  It is Sunday and you watched at least $15$ episodes (N.B.  that's a lot of TV).  The probability of that is $$\frac 17\times .63=.09$$

II.  It is not Sunday and you watched at least $15$ episodes (still a lot of TV).  The probability of that is $$\frac 67\times .57\approx .489$$

Thus the probability that you watched at least $15$ episodes is the sum $$.09+.489 \approx .579$$

Of that the portion which is explained by the "Sunday" route is $.09$ so the answer you want is the ratio $$\frac {.09}{.09+.489}\approx \boxed {\frac 7{45}}$$

And the probability that it is non-Sunday is the compliment, $$\frac {.489}{.09+.489}\approx \boxed {\frac {38}{45}}$$

Note that $\frac 7{45}$ is just a little over $\frac 17$, the probability that it is Sunday having been given no information at all about TV.  This makes sense as the probability of a lot of TV on Sunday is only slightly higher than the probability on a non-Sunday ($63\%$ instead of $57\%$).  Thus watching a lot of TV is evidence for it being Sunday, but it is pretty weak evidence.